# How to get all comments count in vk_api(wall)

Tags: python, vk

I have need to get all user count and id of user using vk_api python lib.

```
vk.wall.getComments()
```

Can get only 100 out time(wall post have 35000), but it have offset, how can use offset to get dict?

I tried to use this, but code give me KeyError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need repeat command with offset=0, offset=100, and so while you  have not empty response. Use list.extend method to make big one list.